# Value is not displayed when I perform a multiplication (C#, Razor Web)

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, razor, webview

I have a problem right now and I don't know why that happens or how I can fix it. My code is very simple and basic.

I have a shopping cart, and when the item Amount is bigger than 10 I only want to show the base amount price, when it's less than 10 I want a 3% discount on the total price.

```js
@foreach (var item in Model.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems)
{
    if(item.Amount <= 10)
    {
        ((@Model.ShoppingCartTotal) * 0.97).ToString("c");
    }
    else if (item.Amount > 10)
    {
        @Model.ShoppingCartTotal.ToString("c")
    }
}
```

When I have more than 10 items it shows the normal price, it would be 11x 9$, which makes 99$. But when it's less than 11 it shows nothing and I don't know why. ShoppingCartTotal is a double in the database

Here are 2 screenshots of the problem on the webview:

[Picture one not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eyQc.jpg)

[Picture two working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXbFC.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried placing some break points inside the if statement ?

Comment: Yes I did, nothing special happens. It says the item.Amount for each ShoppingCart counter, like expected. No error or something like that

Comment: And what about the value of @Model.ShoppingCartTotal (while debugging)

Comment: On the side note `Quantity` would be a better term if it is to used for how many items are added to the cart ..

Comment: Did you check if the foreach loop even executes..

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the multiplication logic in your view model like this

```
 public string SomeNewPropertyName => Amount <= 10 ? (ShoppingCartTotal) * 0.97).ToString("c") : ShoppingCartTotal.ToString("c");
```

and then in your foreach statment just view your new property instead of the if statment. and wrap it with a < span > or < p > element